# Strange space at bottom of page on iOS

Tags: html, css

Page here: http://teamcherry.com.au/introducing-hollow-knight/#more-116

For some reason a large white space appears under the footer on this page, but only on mobile safari (iPhone/iPad). Footer displays perfectly on Chrome, Firefox and desktop Safari.

Any idea what the issue is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the

```
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

IOS7 has issues with rendering VH units anywayway but maybe try setting your body height to just 100% if its a full-height section hack your after.

[Caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) explains it in more detail.

But without any use case for why you need that min-height property we can't help much

also try checking out this pollyfill, it may fix your issues

[viewport units pollyfill](https://github.com/rodneyrehm/viewport-units-buggyfill)